# SQL Server 2014 Data Collection and Exception

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a data collection in SQL Server 2014 but when I try to run one against the disk summary it throws the following error:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation --> Object reference net set to an instance of an object.
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a programming error. You should try updating with CU1 (release last week), and if it does not work, you should open a case with Microsoft / [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com)